# How to use async await inside another async function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

i have a question about using async await inside another promise. I have a function call another function to get a transaction details.

When i running the function LastTransactions the field details do not show results. Anyone can help me ?

```
LastTransactions: async (transactionKey, page) => {

    const api = `https://api.pagar.me/1/payables?recipient_id=${transactionKey}&count=${totalResults}&page=${page}&api_key=${PagarmeApiKey}`;
    const response = await axios.get(api);

    transactions = response.data.map((item) => {

      return {
        id : item.id,
        transactionId : item.transaction_id,
        trxDetails : [transactionDetails(item.transaction_id)],
      }

    });

    return transactions;

  },
```

and a detail function

```
async function transactionDetails(id){
    const response = await axios.get(`https://api.pagar.me/1/transactions/${id}?api_key=${PagarmeApiKey}`)
    const data = response.data;
    return data;
}
```

Comment: `transactionDetails` returns a promise. Map an async function over your array so you can await calls to it. `const transactionPromises = response.data.map(async item =>...);` then `return await Promise.all(transactionPromises)`

Answer (score 7):

You need to utilize the `Promise.all` method to take an array of promises and return  an array with your transactions once each individual call for transaction details finishes.

```js
async (transactionKey, page) => {
  const api = 
    `https://api.pagar.me/1/payables?recipient_id=${transactionKey}&count=${totalResults}&page=${page}&api_key=${PagarmeApiKey}`;
  const response = await axios.get(api);
  
  // create an array of promises and wait for
  // all of them to resolve before continuing
  const transactions = await Promise.all(
    response.data.map(async item => {
      const { id, transaction_id } = item;

      // get transaction details for each item in the array
      const trxDetails = await transactionDetails(transaction_id);

      return {
        id,
        trxDetails,
        transactionId: transaction_id,
      };
    })
  );
  return transactions;
};
```

References:

- [Promise.all() - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Answer (score 0):

Since `transactionDetails(item.transaction_id)` is Asynchronous, you need to await that as well, otherwise it will return immediately and trxDetails will contain a promise object, and not response.data.

try this:

```
transactions = response.data.map(async (item) => {

      return {
        id : item.id,
        transactionId : item.transaction_id,
        trxDetails : [await transactionDetails(item.transaction_id)],
      }

    });
```

Comment: i try o use the two options but i receive a blank array like this. I look the functions transactionsDetails to check if data API is OK and i can print the data but i cant set the results in details : array
```
[
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {}
]
```

Comment: Which object are you printing which gives you this array of empty objects?