# React Native Alarm Notification: Alarms set successfully but notification is comes only once for multiple alarms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Basically, I am working on an application which reminds a patient the time schedule for his eye drops. A user can set multiple alarms for a given day or multiple days. Alarms should be called noOfDays*howOftenPerDay times. In my code

- When a user sets one alarm, we can get it from the ReactNativeAN.getScheduledAlarms(), the alarm rings and it works fine
- When a user sets two alarms, we can get it from the ReactNativeAN.getScheduledAlarms(), the second alarm rings only but not the first one
- When a user sets three alarms, we can get it from the ReactNativeAN.getScheduledAlarms(), the 3rd alarm only rings but not the first two
- I tried using

> channel: Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1)),

I thought it maybe a channel issue but it didn't work

Can someone please help me fix this issue? Any help would be highly appreciated and here is the full piece of code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Picker, Text, View, Image, Button, Alert } from 'react-native'
import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox'
import DatePicker from 'react-native-datepicker'
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import DateTimePickerModal from "react-native-modal-datetime-picker";
import ReactNativeAN from 'react-native-alarm-notification';
import moment from 'moment'

import styles from './style'

export default class AddDropForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            date: new Date(),
            mode: 'date',
            show: false,
            alarmComponent: [],
            isDatePickerVisible: false,
            time: new Date(),
            dayPickerShow: false,
            oftenPickerShow: false,
            taperPickerShow: false,
            noOfDays: 1,
            howOften: 1,
            taper: 1,
            isLeftSelected: false,
            isRightSelected: false,
            isBothSelected: false,
            timeArray: []
        }
    }


    updateNoOfDays = (count) => {
        this.setState({ noOfDays: count })
    }
    updateHowOften = (count) => {
        this.setState({ howOften: count })
    }
    updateTaper = (count) => {
        this.setState({ taper: count })
    }

    showDatePicker = () => {
        this.setState({ isDatePickerVisible: true })
    };

    hideDatePicker = () => {
        this.setState({ isDatePickerVisible: false })
    };

    handleConfirm = (date) => {
        console.log("A date has been picked: ", date);
        this.setState({ timeArray: [...this.state.timeArray, date] })
        this.setState({ time: date })
        this.hideDatePicker();
    };

    async setAlarm(name) {
        let setTime = ''
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.noOfDays; i++) {
            this.state.timeArray.forEach(async t => {
                let alarmData = {
                    title: `${name}`,
                    message: `Reminder for ${name}`,
                    channel: Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1)),
                    small_icon: "ic_launcher",
                    auto_cancel: true,
                    schedule_type: "repeat",
                    sound_name: 'alarm_quartz.mp3',
                    has_button: true
                };
                console.log("The set time is: " + setTime)
                setTime = moment(t).set({ second: 0, millisecond: 0 }).add(i, 'days').format('DD-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss')
                await ReactNativeAN.scheduleAlarm({ ...alarmData, fire_date: setTime });
            })
        }
        Alert.alert('Alarms Set')
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Schedule')
    }

    formatDate() {
        let date = this.state.time
        var hours = date.getHours();
        var minutes = date.getMinutes();
        var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
        hours = hours % 12;
        hours = hours ? hours : 12;
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
        var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
        return strTime;
    }

    render() {
        const { dropName } = this.props.route.params
        let array = []
        for (let i = 1; i <= this.state.howOften; i++) {
            array.push(
                <View style={{ flex: 7 }}>
                    <Button title={"Set Time"} onPress={() => this.showDatePicker()} />
                    <DateTimePickerModal
                        isVisible={this.state.isDatePickerVisible}
                        mode="time"
                        onConfirm={this.handleConfirm}
                        onCancel={this.hideDatePicker}
                    />
                </View>
            )
        }
        // const { dropName } = this.props
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.topTitleContainer}>
                    <View style={{ flex: 2 }}>
                        <Image style={{ width: 70, height: 60 }} source={require('../../../assets/addDrop.png')} />
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ flex: 7 }}>
                        <Text style={styles.titleText}>
                            {dropName.name}
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.tilesContainer}>
                    <View style={{ flex: 2 }}>
                        <Text style={styles.subTitle}>Which Eye?</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.checkBoxContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.subTitle}>Left</Text>
                        <CheckBox
                            value={this.state.isLeftSelected}
                            onValueChange={(newValue) => this.setState({ isLeftSelected: newValue, isBothSelected: false, isRightSelected: false })
                            }
                            style={styles.checkbox}
                        />
                        <Text style={styles.subTitle}>Both</Text>
                        <CheckBox
                            value={this.state.isBothSelected}
                            onValueChange={(newValue) => this.setState({
                                isBothSelected: newValue, isLeftSelected: false,
                                isRightSelected: false
                            })
                            }
                            style={styles.checkbox}
                        />
                        <Text style={styles.subTitle}>Right</Text>
                        <CheckBox
                            value={this.state.isRightSelected}
                            onValueChange={(newValue) => this.setState({ isRightSelected: newValue, isLeftSelected: false, isBothSelected: false })
                            }
                            style={styles.checkbox}
                        />
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.tilesContainer}>
                    <View style={{ flex: 2 }}>
                        <Text style={styles.subTitle}>Start Date?</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ flex: 7 }}>
                        <DatePicker
                            style={{ width: '100%' }}
                            date={this.state.date}
                            mode="date"
                            placeholder="select date"
                            format="YYYY-MM-DD"
                            minDate={new Date()}
                            confirmBtnText="Confirm"
                            cancelBtnText="Cancel"
                            customStyles={{
                                dateIcon: {
                                    position: 'absolute',
                                    left: 0,
                                    top: 4,
                                    marginLeft: 0
                                },
                                dateInput: {
                                    marginLeft: 36
                                }
                            }}
                            onDateChange={(date) => { this.setState({ date: date }) }}
                        />
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.tilesContainer}>
                    <View style={{ flex: 2 }}>
                        <Text style={styles.subTitle}>Number of Days?</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ flex: 7 }}>
                        <Picker selectedValue={this.state.noOfDays} onValueChange={this.updateNoOfDays}>
                            ...
                        </Picker>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.tilesContainer}>
                    <View style={{ flex: 2 }}>
                        <Text style={styles.subTitle}>How Often?</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ flex: 7 }}>
                        <Picker selectedValue={this.state.howOften} onValueChange={this.updateHowOften}>
                           ...
                        </Picker>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.tilesContainer}>
                    <View style={{ flex: 2 }}>
                        <Text style={styles.subTitle}>Taper Drops?</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ flex: 7 }}>
                        <Picker selectedValue={this.state.taper} onValueChange={this.updateTaper}>
                           ...
                           
                        </Picker>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.tilesContainer}>
                    <View style={{ flex: 2 }}>
                        <Text style={styles.subTitle}>Alarm</Text>
                    </View>
                    {array}
                </View>
                <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    <View style={{ width: 260 }}>
                        <Button title={"Add"} color='#57E874' onPress={() => this.setAlarm(dropName.name)} />
                    </View>

                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you have to add **repeat_interval: "minutely"** and ** interval_value: 3** if this options worked refer the npm document once more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found the issue. The library you are using is setting the `alarmId` to a timestamp.

When you run your `for loop` and you call `ReactNativeAN.scheduleAlarm` and the native function runs, `NSDate.date.timeIntervalSince1970` returns the same value for each iteration which means each (previous) Alarm is getting overwritten.

Here's a simple function to simulate this theory.

```js
const items = [1,2,3,4,5];

items.forEach(item => {
  console.log(Date.now()); // Same timestamp logged and therefore alarmId is not unique.
});
```

Frustratingly the library doesn't support `alarmId` as a property, you could forcibly add a wait so that the timestamp is different.

```js
const items = [1,2,3,4,5];

items.forEach((item, index) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(Date.now()); // alarmId will now be unique.
    // Code to call ReactNativeAN.scheduleAlarm
  }, index + 1);
});
```

For sanity sake, you can assign the value of `ReactNativeAN.scheduleAlarm` to a variable and log it out to make sure its the value you're expecting.

```
const alarm = await ReactNativeAN.scheduleAlarm(...);

console.log(alarm);
```

Comment: you are absolutely right, the issue is same what you told. But can you please show me how does it really looks like a fixed for loop?

Comment: Moreover it is saying Error: failed to schedule alarm because fire date is in the past, could it be due to difference in time zones?

Comment: Moreover When I pick up a time from date picker and set the alarm it says: [Fri Aug 06 2021 06:21:33.784]  LOG      A date has been picked:  2021-08-06T06:26:48.000Z       Error: failed to schedule alarm because fire date is in the past

Answer (score 1):

i guess issue is in your channel, are you sure it must be different per alarm

Comment: how I can make it different per alarm?

Comment: what's the result of this function: uuidv4()

Comment: it returns a string, I tried using random numbers using Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1)) as well but that's not working too @kingofday

Comment: did you tried not variable channel name, maybe if it would be static problem goes away

Comment: I just came to know that the problem is with the loop, alarms run/fire noOfDays time, I just need to ask how to run them noOfDays * howOftenPerDay. Can you help me fixing the loop?

Comment: witch prop you talking about, or you mean your code?

Comment: I mean my code, alarm is set fine but " setTime = moment(t).set({ second: 0, millisecond: 0 }).add(i, 'days').format('DD-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss') " and "await ReactNativeAN.scheduleAlarm({ ...alarmData, fire_date: setTime })" lines have issue. These lines are responsible for firing alarms. Alarms are set fine but not fired fine.

Comment: did you log to check the date time you generating

Comment: Yes they are absolutely correct, I can see them from getScheduleAlarm function as well. But issue is with fire alram line only

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the way you're using async await is optimal might be why it's causing you issues, You need to utilize the Promise.all method to take an array of promises and return an array with your scheduled Alarms once each individual call for `ReactNativeAN.scheduleAlarm` finishes.

Look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62980590/10791931)

Also I agree with the other comment I'm not sure the channel should be different for each alarm in the documentation it says *Specifies the channel the notification should be delivered on..* so if the notifications are for the same user I think it should be the same id.

Comment: When I pick up a time from date picker and set the alarm it says: [Fri Aug 06 2021 06:21:33.784]  LOG      A date has been picked:  2021-08-06T06:26:48.000Z       Error: failed to schedule alarm because fire date is in the past